# How do I make this SQL Select clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select

I need help making this query into English even. 
I have a table `DEVICE` with a `DEVICEID` column, and a table `CLONE` with the columns `DEVICEID`, `CLONEID`, `PATH`, AND `VALUE`.

I want to get the devices that are *not* linked to a `CLONE` where the `PATH` is in a hard coded set we can call `A` (8 hard coded values) and the `PATH's` `VALUE` is not in `B`.

Can I get help thinking this through?

My first attempt was

```
SELECT d 
    FROM device d, clone c 
    WHERE d.deviceid = c.deviceid 
        AND (c.path = 'a[1]' OR c.path = 'a[2]' ... ) 
        AND x.value not in B
```

But the OR for each path is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `A` and `B` are lists of values

```
select d from device d where not exists (select c.device_id from
clone c where d.deviceid = c.deviceid and c.path in (A) and
c.value not in (B)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select d 
from device d
where not exists (select * from clone c where c.deviceid=d.deviceid 
and (c.path = 'a[1]' OR c.path = 'a[2]')
        and c.value not in ('hardcoded list')
        )
```